# Fastest fill memory with specified 64-bit value

Tags: c#, assembly, delphi

I need to fast fill a memory block in C#, so I wrote something like this (in Free Pascal Compiler + Lazarus in 64 bit mode):

```
//  ECX = Ptr64
//  EDX = Count
//  R8  = Value

PROCEDURE Fill64 (VAR Ptr64; Count: QWord; Value: QWord);
BEGIN
  ASM
    PUSH    RDI
    MOV     RDI, RCX    // Destination Index = Ptr64
    MOV     RAX, R8     // Accumulator = Value
    MOV     RCX, RDX    // Counter Register = Count
    TEST    RCX, RCX    // If RCX is 0, set ZF (zero flag)
    JZ      @Exit       // Exit if ZF is set
    REP     STOSQ       // Fill memory using 64 bit value from RAX register
  @Exit:
    POP     RDI
  END;
END;
```

And I use it from C#:

```
[DllImport ("MemUtil64.dll", EntryPoint = "Fill64", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern unsafe void Fill64 (void* ptr, ulong count, ulong value);
```

If this code okay, and fastest possible?

Comment: have you tested it against other possible implementations for speed?

Comment: The code is okay if unsafe is okay for you. You should understand that there is a possible vulnerability.  Regarding performance, I see your question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178211/filling-memory-using-specified-value-performance), it has a good link in comments. Probably SSE would be faster.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard: Speed is OK, and its around 3GB/s when AIDA64 tells I have 5,5GB/s memory. It can be faster, but need SSE and advanced cache/tlb optimizations which I cannot understand. Comparing to pure C#, its 50% faster.

Comment: @Kefir: Yes, I will delete this stack overflow duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is CPU-dependent. For example [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap/+/038b0a6d8d32db934bba6a24e74e76e4e327a94f/arch/x86_64/lib/memset.S) is Android's memset implementation: it uses `rep stosq` for some CPUs and a different more complicated implementation (avoiding `rep stosq`) for others.

For further details, on Intel CPUs, refer to the "Enhanced REP MOVSB and STOSB operation (ERMSB)" section of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32
Architectures
Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Rep Stosq is enough fast for me. Gives me 60% of mem bandwidth on my cpu. That optimization guide anyway is very useful.